# URLs and Regex in Django

Tags: python, regex, django

I want my link detail url like this: /subreddit/pk/slug

Subreddit(category) is variable of course.

In Reddit if you click the comments of the link, you are going to detail of it. But detail page is mix of subreddit. How can I do that?

I hope I made myself clear. Thanks in advance.

I'm putting here some URLs code example:

## base/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include("x.links.urls", namespace="link")),
    url(r'^k/', include("x.subreddit.urls", namespace="sub")),
]
```

## link/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<pk>\d+)(?:/(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+))?/$',
        view=views.LinkDetailView.as_view(),
        name='link_detail'
    ),
]
```

## subreddit/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
    regex=r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
        view=views.SubredditDetailView.as_view(),
        name='subreddit_detail'
    ),
]
```

Comment: No, you really didn't make yourself clear, unfortunately. What is your actual question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman , My english is not good. So i have difficulties. I want to link detail page urls look like this: /subreddit(category_name)/pk/slug. 

Right now just /pk/slug.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the order of URL include. It take priority as first come first server.In you case it running the links URL,because there is match to your URL pattern.  If you declare like below.

```
 urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^k/', include("x.subreddit.urls", namespace="sub")),
        url(r'^', include("x.links.urls", namespace="link")),
 ]
```

It will first match k then go to link urls.

Comment: But when I go http://127.0.0.1:8000/k/subreddit/pk/slug give error.(Page not found (404)
)

Subreddit means category name of the link.

Answer (score 0):

In `link/urls.py` try to add regex that parses arguments of your desired url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<pk>\d+)(?:/(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+))?/$',
        view=views.LinkDetailView.as_view(),
        name='link_detail'
    ),
    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<subreddit>[\w-]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+)/$',
        view=views.SubredditDetailView.as_view(),
        name='subreddit_detail'
    ),
]
```

The second URL-pattern will pass arguments `subreddit`, `pk` and `slug` to the subreddit view function.

Comment: Doesn't work. Still same url. /pk/slug. When I try to go url it's given me error. Page not found(404)

Comment: @Yunus, did you restart your server? Django sometimes needs a restart when editing URL's configuration.

Comment: Yes but it didn't work. When I change the just the link_detail part to 

  `url(
        regex=r'^k/(?P<subreddit>[\w-]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)(?:/(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+))?/$',
        view=views.LinkDetailView.as_view(),
        name='link_detail'
    ),`
it's work. But now is accepting whatever you write in the subreddit section of the url. Let's say: You write 127.0.0.1:8000/k/there_is_no_name_like_that_in_the_database/pk/slug
this. You are going to this page but there is no subreddit with this name. 

I don't know why it's doing this.